# C# Unity Queue emptying itself

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, queue, 2d

I have trouble figuring out a bug. My game initializes several queues to store the game prompts and, in the "Start" button, the function `StartDialogue()` fills each of the queues and goes to `DisplayNext()`. The `DisplayNext()` function is supposed to dequeue the first prompt from certain queues and put them into the dialogue boxes. Afterwards, the player selects the correct button to answer and it calls `DisplayNext()` to advance to the next prompt.

However, my problem is that my `sen_queue` count is setting itself to 0 when the correct button calls `DisplayNext()`. The debug output first displays 4 when "Start" is pressed, but when the correct button is pressed, it displays 0. With the first correct button press, it goes to the `EndDialogue()` function. I have attached my code below. I have no clue how to fix this so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!
However, my problem is that my `sen_queue` count is setting itself to 0 when the correct button calls `DisplayNext()`. The debug output first displays 4 when "Start" is pressed, but when the correct button is pressed it displays 0. With the first correct button press it goes to the `EndDialogue()` function. I have attached my code below. I have no clue how to fix this, so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much in advance!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class QuestionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text dialogueText;
    public Text topText;
    public Text botText;

    public Queue<string> sen_queue;
    public Queue<string> top_queue;
    public Queue<string> bot_queue;
    public Queue<string> wrong_queue;

    private bool prev_wrong;

    public GameObject finalsaltwater;
    public GameObject water;
    public GameObject sand;
    public GameObject salt;
    public GameObject filtersand;
    public GameObject platewater;


    void Start()
    {
        Screen.SetResolution(1600, 900, true);

        sen_queue = new Queue<string>();
        top_queue = new Queue<string>();
        bot_queue = new Queue<string>();
        wrong_queue = new Queue<string>();
        prev_wrong = false;

        finalsaltwater.SetActive(false);
        filtersand.SetActive(false);
        platewater.SetActive(false);
    }


    public void StartDialogue(Question question, Question topprompt, Question botprompt, Question wrong)
    {
        sen_queue.Clear();
        top_queue.Clear();
        bot_queue.Clear();
        wrong_queue.Clear();

        foreach (string sentence in question.sentences)
        {
            sen_queue.Enqueue(sentence);
        }
        foreach (string sentence in topprompt.sentences)
        {
            top_queue.Enqueue(sentence);
        }
        foreach (string sentence in botprompt.sentences)
        {
            bot_queue.Enqueue(sentence);
        }
        foreach (string sentence in wrong.sentences)
        {
            wrong_queue.Enqueue(sentence);
        }

        DisplayNext();
    }


    IEnumerator ToggleFalse(GameObject thing)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        thing.SetActive(false);
    }


    IEnumerator ToggleTrue(GameObject thing)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        thing.SetActive(true);
    }


    public void DisplayNext()
    {
        Debug.Log("IN DISPLAY " + sen_queue.Count);

        if (sen_queue.Count == 0)
        {
            EndDialogue();
            return;
        }

        if (top_queue.Count == 2)
        {
            platewater.SetActive(true);
            water.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(ToggleFalse(salt));
        } else if (top_queue.Count == 1)
        {
            filtersand.SetActive(true);
            sand.SetActive(false);
            platewater.SetActive(false);
            StartCoroutine(ToggleTrue(finalsaltwater));
        } else if (top_queue.Count == 0)
        {
            platewater.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(ToggleTrue(salt));
            StartCoroutine(ToggleFalse(platewater));
            finalsaltwater.SetActive(false);
        }

        string sentence = sen_queue.Dequeue();

        if (top_queue.Count != 0)
        {
            string topbutton = top_queue.Dequeue();
            topText.text = topbutton;
        }
        if (bot_queue.Count != 0)
        {
            string botbutton = bot_queue.Dequeue();
            botText.text = botbutton;
        }
        prev_wrong = false;
        dialogueText.text = sentence;
    }


    public void IncorrectDisplay()
    {
        if (wrong_queue.Count == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (prev_wrong == false)
        {
            string wrong_sen = wrong_queue.Dequeue();
            dialogueText.text = wrong_sen;
        }
        prev_wrong = true;
    }


    public void EndDialogue()
    {
        dialogueText.text = "Good job! Refresh the page if you want to restart.";
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try [debugging](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat late, but I had the same issue. And even if you've already solved the problem, maybe I can help some other people in the future!
It has something to do with the calling order. In my code I had 2 Start() methods in 2 different classes.

In the class DialogueTrigger:

```
public Dialogue dialogue;

public void Start()
{
    triggerDialogue();
}

public void triggerDialogue()
{
    FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>().startDialogue(dialogue);
}
```

And in the class DialogueManager:

```
public Queue<string> sentences;
private bool dialogueStarted;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    sentences = new Queue<string>();

}

private void Update()
{
    if(dialogueStarted && Input.GetKeyDown(GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<Controls>().confirm))
    {
        displayNextSentence();
    }
}

public void startDialogue(Dialogue dialogue)
{

    print("start:" + dialogue.name);
    sentences.Clear();

    foreach (string s in dialogue.sentences)
    {
        sentences.Enqueue(s);
    }

    displayNextSentence();
    dialogueStarted = true;
}

public void displayNextSentence()
{
    if (sentences.Count == 0)
    {
        endDialogue();
        return;
    }

    string sentence = sentences.Dequeue();

    Debug.Log(sentence);
}


private void endDialogue()
{
    Debug.Log("End of dialogue");
    dialogueStarted = false;
}
```

Instead of clicking a button I let the next string come in when pressing a key (spacebar), but it should work the same.
The problem was that the Start() of DialogueManager got called after the startDialogue()-method (which gets called in the Start() of DialogueTrigger), gets called second. This resets the whole queue, makes it empty and thus sets the length to 0. This means the press of the key doesn't reset the queue, but it happens automatically!
In your code for some reason the Start() method gets called after the button press. 
The solution to is to put the following code at the top of your StartDialogue()-method:

```
if (sentences == null)
{
    sentences = new Queue<string>();
}
```

You could probably also leave the if-statement out and then use this code instead of the Clear()-methods. I haven't tested this, but the result should be the same. If you want to use Clear(), it would be better to use the if-statement. If you still leave it in you would reset the queue twice, which would be unnecessary.